# How to write text channel message history to .txt?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a command for my Discord bot that will write the channel history to a .txt.

I have tried several different attempts using channel.history().flatten(). I'm sure there are significant issues with my code and I apologize for that. I am quite new to this and haven't entirely grasped the concepts. Thanks so much.

```
@client.command(name="history")
async def history():
    channel_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    messages = await channel.history(channel_id).flatten()
    with open("channel_messages.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(f"{messages}")
```

Comment: It is not wise to name your opened file handler `f` if you also want use it as `f"{}"` format

Comment: @mrangry777 Why? the two have nothing to do with each other. `f` is a good, typical name for a file in a `with` scope (even though linters do complain about it).

Comment: @mrangry777You do not seems to be familiar with the f-strings concept added in Python 3.6. This snippet is perfectly good.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph for the same reasons linters complain about it. Valid code is not the same as easily readable one for me lines like this `f.write(f"{messages}")` is error prone.Side note there was no information of python version used.

Comment: @mrangry777 You misunderstood my comment: *The linter is **wrong** in this instance*. The code *is* readable, not merely valid (that’s why I wrote that the code is “good” and “typical”). You claim that the line is error-prone but you don’t give evidence and I claim that you’re wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to pass an id to [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)

```
@client.command()
async def history(ctx, limit: int = 100):  
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=limit).flatten()
    with open("channel_messages.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(*messages, sep="\n\n", file=f)
```

Other changes: removed the `name=` because it uses the name of the callback by default, every command needs an [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) to be passed, I added a `limit` argument so you can control how many messages to get, and I changed the `write` to a `print` with a `file` argument, because I think that make it easier to control what gets written to the file.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you so much. The purpose of me trying to use the channel id was to get the history of a specific channel (without having to trigger the command within it). Also, is there anyway for me to use ctx.author, ctx.content, ctx.channel on this when structuring the channel_messages.txt file rather than dumping everything ctx.channel.history returns?

Comment: Sure, you can do something like `for message in messages: print(f"{message.author.name} | {message.channel.name} | {message.content}", file=f)`